# What ending do you get with brainless Randy?

Tags: illbleed

In Illbleed, if you rescue all your friends you get the "good" ending (with them sitting around on a beach, wondering what to do with all of the prize money). But if you rescue Randy without getting his brain back first, he can't talk properly in cutscenes after that (especially, and hilariously, notable if you use him for the "Killerman" stage).

So what kind of ending do you get for the game if you rescue everyone, but leave Randy brainless? The bad ending (as if you failed to save some of them)? The normal good ending (with Randy miraculously being able to talk normally again)? Or a variation of the good ending with him speaking gibberish like in other cutscenes?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that he's able to speak normally during the beach scene if you skip getting his brain. I KNOW you don't get the bad ending. I can only assume his friends used some of their prize money to help him out...